# How to redirect NullPointerExceptions in Struts?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

is there a way to redirect all NullPointerExceptions to a pretty jsp page perhaps in Struts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `struts-config.xml` configuration that allows you to define a exception hanbler:

```
  <global-exceptions>
    <exception handler="br.com.nostrum.radiomanager.exception.RadioManagerExceptionHandler" key="exception" type="java.lang.Exception" />
  </global-exceptions>
```

Here we catched java.lang.Exception and his descendants but you can changed to NullPointerException. An the handler should extend org.apache.struts.action.ExceptionHandler and forward via mapping.findForward (like @Kevin Crowell said) or other method of yous choice.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's a request scoped EXCEPTION object that will contain the exception.  See:

http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-core/apidocs/constant-values.html

and the following key:

```
org.apache.struts.action.EXCEPTION
```

There are then various ways to print that out in the JSP, e.g using a Struts bean tag:

```
<logic:equal name="org.apache.struts.action.EXCEPTION" value="java.lang.NullPointerException" scope="request">
  <bean:write property="org.apache.struts.action.EXCEPTION"/>
</logic:equal>
```

This is all Struts 1.x however.  I'm sure Struts 2 has a similar way.